# JSON_CONTAINS not working in django queryset but working fine at mysql workbench

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a list of devices in my database, like this:

```
id: 1, category_json: [1, 3]
id: 2, category_json: [1, 4]
id: 3, category_json: [4, 35]
```

The field 'category_json' is a JSONField. I get an array of categories that the users wants from the frontend like this:

```
categories = [3]
```

I need to make a query in django to look up for all devices that has any of the categories above, I did this in django:

```
category_filtering = None
for category in categories:
    if not category_filtering:
        category_filtering = Q(category_json__contains=category)
    else:
        category_filtering = category_filtering | Q(category_json__contains=category)
all_devices: QuerySet = Device.objects.filter(Q(status=1) & Q(company__in=companies)) & category_filtering
```

That code above reproduces the following query:

```
SELECT `devices`.`id`, `devices`.`serial`, `devices`.`title`, `devices`.`product_id`, `devices`.`company_id`, `devices`.`server_access_key`, `devices`.`device_local_access_key`, `devices`.`mac_address`, `devices`.`status`, `devices`.`owner_device_id`, `devices`.`connected_equipament`, `devices`.`gps_x`, `devices`.`gps_y`, `devices`.`profile_id`, `devices`.`softwareVer`, `devices`.`hardwareVer`, `devices`.`isVirtual`, `devices`.`timezone`, `devices`.`installed_phase`, `devices`.`installation_local`, `devices`.`group`, `devices`.`relay_state`, `devices`.`last_sync`, `devices`.`phases_ordering`, `devices`.`created_at`, `devices`.`installation_date`, `devices`.`installation_state`, `devices`.`last_change`, `devices`.`last_online`, `devices`.`comments`, `devices`.`enable_bbd_home`, `devices`.`enable_bbd_pro`, `devices`.`enable_tseries_analytics`, `devices`.`enable_gd_production`, `devices`.`card_profile_id`, `devices`.`firmware_app_ver`, `devices`.`firmware_metrol_ver`, `devices`.`commissioning_date`, `devices`.`state`, `devices`.`area_square_meters`, `devices`.`category`, `devices`.`local`, `devices`.`code`, `devices`.`enable_advanced_monitoring`, `devices`.`send_data`, `devices`.`olson_timezone`, `devices`.`language`, `devices`.`extra_fields`, `devices`.`category_json` FROM `devices` WHERE (`devices`.`status` = 1 AND `devices`.`company_id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `companies` U0 WHERE (U0.`id` IN ((
        WITH RECURSIVE ids(id) as (
        select 297 as id
        union all
        select companies.id as id from ids join companies where ids.id = companies.company_owner
        )
        select id from ids)) AND U0.`is_active` = True)) AND JSON_CONTAINS(`devices`.`category_json`, (CAST("3" AS JSON))))
```

In django is returning an empty Queryset, like this:

```
all_devices <QuerySet []>
```

But when I just copy this query and run in MySQL Workbench, it works fine, it brings the device I want. What am I doing wrong??

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: How exactly did you get the raw SQL query?

Comment: print(all_devices.query)